# Split SQL-table into multiple tables based on value in a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like the following in SQL Server. All nvarchar datatypes.

```
ID        Price      Supplier
515       1           A
516       2           A
517       3           A
515       1.1         B
516       1.9         B
```

and I want to put a sql/stored procedure which results in side by side comparison of data by Supplier. So split by supplier and compare by ID.

```
ID        Price      Supplier  ID2  price2 Supplier2
515       1           A        515  1.1    B
516       2           A        516  1.9    B
517       3           A
```

Number of suppliers in a table is always 2. 
Supplier Name can vary as the data coming to the table is dynamic. 
Might be a case where supplier 2 data is missing completely.

How do I put a sql for this ?

Comment: For SQL Server use PIVOT

Comment: How many suppliers can an ID have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a self-join:

```
SELECT a.*
      ,b.ID ID2
      ,b.Price Price2
      ,b.Supplier Supplier2
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
  ON a.ID = b.ID
  AND a.Supplier <> b.Supplier
WHERE a.Supplier = 'a'
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1242/1/0)

This assumes Supplier `A` always exists, if that isn't the case you could use a `FULL JOIN` and `COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID)`.

**Update:**  Since `A` was a sample value and actual values can vary, creating a `ROW_NUMBER()` will allow you to use the self-join method:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Supplier) RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT a.ID
      ,a.Price
      ,a.Supplier
      ,b.ID ID2
      ,b.Price Price2
      ,b.Supplier Supplier2
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.ID = b.ID
  AND a.Supplier <> b.Supplier
WHERE a.RN = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1242/3/0)

Comment: Not necessarily Supplier 'a ' will always be there. A and B just used as example. Data coming to the table is dynamic.

Comment: @buffer_overflow Is the number of values also dynamic, or will there just be 2?

Comment: There will always be two supplier in table.

Comment: At least 2 or Maximum of 2 suppliers?

Comment: @buffer_overflow See update which removes reliance on a specific value for the supplier.

Comment: Any alternative to using 'with cte approach ? The table I have mentioned is what I am deriving after joins with 8 tables. With this approach I will have to store it in a temp table first and use that as a table.

Comment: @buffer_overflow You could add the `ROW_NUMBER()` to the query that creates the referenced table, but not sure what else you'd do.

Comment: Agreed. Don't think there is other dynamic approach to this problem. Pivot will aggregate which I do not want.